# Open specific page of a PDF using QGIS actions

Tags: qgis, pdf, actions

Can anyone help me with the syntax to open a `.pdf`-file at a specific page using a QGIS action? For example, a 50 page pdf has the information of use at page 8, so invoking the action in the QGIS Map Window will open the `.pdf` at page 8

The qgis Table has 2 columns, one with the location of the `.pdf` document and one with the page number.

Is this even possible within QGIS?

Comment: You should the default action provided in the Layer Properties. There is one similar to this request I think

Comment: I have tried using the Python code posted by Vincent, except I have edited the 4th line so that the page that opens is dictated by a field called "Image" (please see below). The code correctly opens up the page dictated by the field, however it causes QGIS to crash, is there an extra line I need to add at the end of the code to end the process? import subprocess import os path_to_pdf = os.path.abspath(r'\\ad.islington.gov.uk\Service Areas\EandR\Traffic & Transportation\01 Service Areas\04 BS\03 Business Sys\01 Div Devel\01 Traf Orders\04 MADE ORDERS\[% "path" %]') # path of your pdf file in th

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following **Python** action:

```
import subprocess
import os
path_to_pdf = os.path.abspath(r'[% "path" %]') # path of your pdf file in the field path
path_to_acrobat = os.path.abspath(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe') # path of acrobat reader
process = subprocess.Popen([path_to_acrobat, '/A', 'page=3', path_to_pdf], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) # change the page number
process.wait()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, that has worked a treat!!

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer you can validate my answer indicate your problem has been solved.

Comment: Note the above hard-codes the path to Acrobat Reader DC in the 4th line. If you're using this only on your local machine, and it works, great. If not, find where your Acrobat Reader is and change the path. And if you want it to be portable and robust, you'll need to hunt for it in the action or at least expose it as a variable that can be changed by the user.

Comment: If you are having troubles with QGIS crashing, leave away the `process.wait()`. (According to this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/386398/122597)