# Opening PDF w/ action based on variable crashes QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, actions, subprocess

I found this [script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374642/open-specific-page-of-a-pdf-using-qgis-actions?answertab=votes#tab-top) which I modified a bit to open a pdf based on a page number given in the attribute list. Upon trying to execute the action it works just find but QGIS (3.4.15) is crashing!

Any ideas why QGIS is crashing or if there is something not working properly within the code?

My modified code:

```
import subprocess
import os
path_to_pdf = os.path.abspath(r'[% "PDFpath" %]') 
path_to_acrobat = os.path.abspath(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe') 
process = subprocess.Popen([path_to_acrobat, '/A', 'page=[%PDFpage%]', path_to_pdf], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
process.wait()
```

Answer (score 1):

getting rid of

```
process.wait()
```

solved the issue!

Comment: Could you please mark your answer as solution? Thanks! :)